# How come multiple regression has so many assumptions, while advanced machine learning algorithms have next to none?

Tags: python, r

I am analyzing a real-estate dataset. While all regression assumptions fail, my XGBoosting model thrives. Am I missing something? Is XGBoost just the superior model in this case? The dataset is around 67.000 observations and 30 variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Statistics tries to capture the relationship between variables and to model/understand the data (not predict it). ML just gives results and finds a model that is predictive. If your variables don't have a linear relationship to the outcome variable then the main assumption for a linear regressions is violated and a linear model won't work. This article has a pretty good overview of the difference. https://towardsdatascience.com/the-actual-difference-between-statistics-and-machine-learning-64b49f07ea3

Comment: This was honestly very helpful. Great article

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: in my experience XGBoost (and other gradient boosted trees) are often more performant than linear regression for large datasets.

The cases where I have seen (regularized) linear regression outperform XGBoost, I have had very little data which caused the tree based methods to overfit. If you have plenty of observations the easy regularization that linear regression provides is probably outweighed by the ability of other algorithms to find and exploit non linear relationships (obv fairly dataset dependent)

Even though it doesn't directly answer your question, for a great explanation of the differences, see: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9159/when-to-choose-linear-regression-or-decision-tree-or-random-forest-regression

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons for this, in my opinion.

1. Linear regression assumes your y to be linearly related to variables where as tree-based models are considered non-linear models. (So the linearity assumption goes out the window)
2. Breaking some of the linear regression assumptions may not inherently decrease the predictive ability of your model,  but WILL bias the coefficients. Often times, when building a regression model you are trying to determine the effect of an X variable on the Y. In this case you mainly only care about this weight and don't care as much about how well your model predicts. If you are aiming only for predictive ability you can break some assumptions.

These are the main 2 thoughts that come to mind. I would be interested to hear other people's take as well.